# magento show featured product in header

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.7

I am quite newbie to the Magento. Currently I am doing a theme. In that I want to show all the products from featured category. For that I have done a file called `featred.phtml` inside 
`/app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product`. The code for `featured.phtml` is like this

```
<?php $cat_id = 35; ?>
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);?>
<?php $collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position');?>
<?php Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);?>
<?php  $i=0; foreach ($collection as $_product):?>
<?php if($i++%7==0): ?>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
  <?php endif ?>
  <div class="da-slide">
    <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></h2>
    <p class="price"><?php echo $formattedSpecialPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,false);?></p>
    <p><?php echo $_product->_data['short_description']; ?> </p> <br />

    <a class="da-link" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">Shop Now</a>

    <div class="da-img"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(90, 90); ?>" width="120" height="120" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></div>

    <!--.da-img-->

   </div><!--.da-slide-->
   <?php endforeach ?>
    <nav class="da-arrows">
      <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
      <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
    </nav><!--.da-arrows-->
  </div><!--#da-slider-->
 </div><!--.container-->
```

Now Here I am getting al the featured product. After that I want to show all the featured product in my header. For that I have made a block in `page.xml(app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout)` like this

```
<block type="catalog/product_featured" name="product.featured" as="topSlider" translate="label">
  <label>Page Slider</label>
  <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-slider</value></action>
</block>
```

Now I called that block in `header.phtml` like this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSlider'); ?>
```

But after all this I can't see any of the featured product in my home page or in any other pages. So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this issue? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There would be several questions:

1. Have you created the Block-Class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Featured` ?
   1.a You could assign the template via `setTemplate in layout.xml` i hope you do this in the Block-Class!
2. In what `<reference> tag (should be header)` do you add the block via the above layout declaration ?
3. Is the `layout.xml active at all` ?
4. Is your `design package set in System->Configuration` (i would have started in "base" which means base/yourtheme ) ?
5. Is the code in your template actually called - maybe its just an `empty collection` ?